# Does a permutation determined by set of Inversions?

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

For $\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n$, symmetric group on $\{1,2\dots,n\}$ we denote the set of inversions $\{(i,j) | 1\leq i< j\leq n\text{ and }\sigma(i)> \sigma(j)\}$ by $
\mathcal{I}(\sigma)$. I believe that if $
\mathcal{I}(\sigma) =
\mathcal{I}(\tau)$ for any permutations $\sigma,\tau\in\mathfrak{S}_n$, then $\sigma=\tau$. I don’t know how to prove this.

Comment: What have you tried? I recommend trying a few examples. Take some permutations in $S_4$ or $S_5,$ determine $\mathcal I,$ and see how $\mathcal I$ determines back the original permutation, or not.

Comment: Hint: Show that, by counting the number of inversions involving the smallest number, $1$, that you can determine the location of $1$ in the permutation. Once you figure out how that works, rinse and repeat for the larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Mike Earnest, I figured that $|\{(i,j)\in \mathcal{I}(\sigma)| i<j\}|- |\{(a,i)\in \mathcal{I} (\sigma) | a<i\}|+i=\sigma(i)$. Hence set of inversions determines the permutation.